# does orientdb community version offers distributed clustering feature?

Tags: orientdb

what is the difference between OrientDB community and enterprise version when it comes to distributed clustering feature?
will the free community edition offer distributed clustering support as well?

Answer (score 2):

OrientDB community edition has clustering support https://orientdb.com/community-edition/

Answer (score 1):

The Enterprise Edition supports Distributed Clustering Configuration, that is one of the many features like: Query Profiler,Metrics Recording, and Live Monitoring with configurable Alerts.

To more info: http://orientdb.com/why-orientdb/ (Point 6 speaks about Enterprise Edition)

To handle the Distributed Clustering Configuration you can take a look at this link that show you how to configure it: http://orientdb.com/enterprise/last/clustermgmt.html

Finally the differences between Community and Enterprise are that Enterprise supports many features than Community as: Auditing and Advanced Backups (v 2.2 only), Query Profiler and so on.

To more info about the differences: http://orientdb.com/orientdb-enterprise/

Hope it helps

Comment: i have been through these links already and thats what prompted my question as the info is not clear. . thanks for the info.